# What do you call that annoying toddler that whines about everything?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, vocabulary, slang, pejorative-language

You know that kid you see in a supermarket with his/her mom, and the kid is all like: "I don't like that", and starts to scream? What is a good word or slang term for that?

Comment: "Brat" is probably most idiomatic, but "monster" will also work.  Or any of these: holy terror, little terror, crybaby, enfant terrible, rascal, little darling (said with a touch of sarcasm), little devil, horror, hellion, whippersnapper, fiend.

Comment: "Poor little bugger". Just needs some attention.

Comment: I don't.  I blame the parents.

Comment: @Dan Exactly, the parents are responsible for their kids behavior, while they're toddlers, of course, those brats at supermarkets anger me like nothing else

Comment: Tired, probably.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A **brat**.

> a :  child; specifically :  an ill-mannered annoying child *a spoiled
>   brat*
>   b :  an ill-mannered immature person
>
> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brat)

While there are many other terms for this idea, this one is commonly understood in American English.

Comment: In UK we very often add the adjective *spoiled* to *brat*. Quoting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoiled_child *... spoiled child, spoiled brat, or simply a brat* **BUT** further quoting *Perception is an important term, because where the child is suffering a disability such as Autism, observers may judge them as "spoiled" without an understanding of the whole picture. There is no accepted scientific definition of what "spoiled" means, and professionals are often unwilling to use the label because it is considered vague and derogatory*

Answer (score 3):

**Terrible Twos**

Not used so much as a term for the person, but the development stage of that toddler.

*Charlie is in his terrible twos, and it's been so difficult!*

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/terrible-twos) defines as:

*"A stage of development in which toddler behavior is a particular challenge."*

Additionally, this term is widely used throughout parenting ([Parents.com](http://www.parents.com/toddlers-preschoolers/development/behavioral/tackle-terrible-twos/#page=2)) and health ([mayoclinic.org](http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/infant-and-toddler-health/expert-answers/terrible-twos/faq-20058314)) resources.

Comment: and what the kid is doing is 'having a __temper tantrum__'